# Symfony: services._instance_of not work

Tags: symfony

Hello I use the _instance_of options of Symfony.
I am on Symfony 4.1

```
_defaults:
    autowire: true
    public: false
    autoconfigure: true

_instanceof:
    Lle\BpmBundle\Trigger\TriggerInterface:
        tags: [tagged lle.bpm.trigger]

App\Service\DelayTrigger: ~

bpm.service.trigger.chain:
      class:  Lle\BpmBundle\Service\Tag\TriggerChain
      arguments: [!tagged lle.bpm.trigger]
Lle\BpmBundle\Service\Tag\TriggerChain: '@bpm.service.trigger.chain'
```

My class DelayTrigger:

```
namespace App\Service;

use Lle\BpmBundle\Trigger\TriggerInterface;

class DelayTrigger implements TriggerInterface{ ... }
```

The delayTrigger is not in TriggerChain Why ? I do not understand :-S.

If I declare the tag in services it's work:

```
App\Service\DelayTrigger:
    tags : ['lle.bpm.trigger']
```

Sorry for my english, I try to improve that

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
_instanceof:
  Lle\BpmBundle\Trigger\TriggerInterface:
    tags: [tagged lle.bpm.trigger] // You have an error here, what's "tagged"?
```

to

```
_instanceof:
  Lle\BpmBundle\Trigger\TriggerInterface:
    tags: ['lle.bpm.trigger']
```

Basically you're missing `'` and `tagged` is a typo (I suppose)

Comment: Yes thanks it's ok but if I move the "_instanceof" parts in my bundle (vendor/lle/bpmBundle/src/Resources/config/services.yaml) it does not work anymore.

Comment: @JorisSaenger remember that configurations are "per file" so you need to repeat the config everywhere you need it